# Kafka topic alias

Tags: apache-kafka

Is it possible to create an alias of a topic name?

Or, put another way...

If a user writes to topic examplea is it possible to override that at the broker so they actually write to topic exampleb?

alternatively, if the topic was actually written as examplea, but the consumer can refer to it as exampleb.

I'm thinking it could probably be achieved using small hack at the broker where it replies to metadata requests, but I'd rather not if it can be done in some standard way.

Answer (score 1):

Aliases are not natively supported in Kafka.

One workaround could be to produce to `examplea` and have a consumer/producer pair that consumers from `examplea` and produces to `exampleb`. The consumer/producer pair could be written with Kafka clients, as a connector in Connect, as a MirrorMaker instance (though you'll need to modify it to change the topic name), or as a Kafka Streams job. Note that the messages will appear in `exampleb` slightly after `examplea` because they're being copied after being written.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I had thought of using mirror maker to do as you suggest.  I believe v0.9 introduced a message handler that can rewrite messages as they are replicated.  I had also thought of Kafka connect.  My concern with this approach is that the steams end up being written to disk twice, which isn't very efficient.  What I would love is the equivalent of a link on a Linux file system where there can be multiple names referecing the same underlying data.  Thanks again for your suggestion.  I wonder if it is possible to link znodes in zookeeper?

Comment: A quick Google search suggests ZooKeeper does not support znode symlinks, unfortunately.

Comment: Thought not, maybe some day 

Answer (score 0):

How are you writing to the Kafka topic because if it's via a REST proxy you should be able to rewrite the topic portion of the URL using NGINX or a similar reverse proxy intermediary.

Comment: No, Kafka producer  api.  I may consider writing a wrapper around the Java class so that it can rename there.